# In Ruby, I'm capturing some MatchData inside a block but I need the data outside the block

Tags: ruby

Ordinarily, I'd declare the variable outside the block, but you can't declare a MatchData variable. I can do it by querying a match ( e.g. `foo = "hi".match(/hi/)` ) but that feels kinda goofy?

> **Edit:** Question was put on hold, so to be clear, my objective was to capture the result of a `.match` call outside of a block. The simple answer was to declare `foo = nil` outside the block as you don't need to define the var type. Also of use was discovering results are immediately stored in `$~`, `$1`, `$2` etc.  (sorry, this was a bit remedial!)

Comment: you are going to need to provide a little more detail as to what is your problem/question ... btw, i assume you ment foo = "hi".match /hi/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a variable in ruby, you don't need to declare its type, you could simply say it is `nil`, and it should work fine:

```
my_match = nil
"hi there".tap do |x|
  my_match = x.match /hi/
end
puts my_match
# => hi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can'd do `MatchData.new` if that's what you mean, Ruby reports undefined method '`new`' for `MatchData::Class`. Why? Because, in essence, [MatchData is a variable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/MatchData.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> MatchData is the type of the special variable $~, and is the type of
>   the object returned by Regexp#match and Regexp.last_match. It
>   encapsulates all the results of a pattern match, results normally
>   accessed through the special variables $&, $', $`, $1, $2, and so on.

Try this:

```
'string' =~ /s(tr)(ing)/
p $~ #=> #<MatchData "string" 1:"tr" 2:"ing">
p $1 #=> tr
p $2 =#> ing
```

If you want reference the match data variable into something more readable, just do:

```
'string' =~ /s(tr)(ing)/
foo = $~
p foo #=> #<MatchData "string" 1:"tr" 2:"ing">
p foo == $~ #=> true
```